# A feature in aws quicksight to update (put data) redshift from quicksight UserInterface?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-quicksight

Is there any sort of way that I can use quicksight with the help of a text box to update the redshift data with the text in the box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly you want to use QuickSight's dashboard or analysis UI to update data, stored in RedShift. Is that correct?

If my understanding is correct the answer is, unfortunately, "no" at the time of writing this. QuickSight is a BI (business intelligence) tool and, as such, its focus is visualizing data. It lacks mechanisms to make updates, as BI dashboards are meant to be readonly, slice-and-dice, graphical/tabular representations of data.